# How to ignore all folders in Azure Pipelines workspace mapping?

Tags: azure-pipelines

i'm new to Azure Pipelines. I have a project that have a lot of folders inside of it. Let's say I have 100 folders. Project Web depends only of folders Application, Repository and Model.

I tryed to map just the folders I need, but, this way, the solution.sln (in root folder) does not get included in the pipeline.

[image: my Pipeline Workspace configuration]

If I map the root folder, I get solution.sln included, but I get 100 folders of unusable content.

I want to map root folder, but ignore (cloak) all subfolders, except folders Web, Application, Repository and Model. How can I do that?

This is my folder structure.

```
ROOT
├───Solution.sln
├───Web (Folder)
├───Application (Folder)
├───Repository (Folder)
├───Model (Folder)
...
├───Unecessary Folder 1
├───Unecessary Folder 2
├───Unecessary Folder 3
├───Unecessary Folder 4
├───Unecessary Folder 5
```

So, if I map root, I get the Solution.sln included. But a lot of unecessary folders. If I map just the folders I need, I do not get Solution.sln included.

I'm trying to avoid cloak all unecessary folders because new folders are created every week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to map folders Web, Application, Repository, Mode and file Solution.sln, you can map the .sln file directly in Workspace mapping. Please check the pic below.

In my project, I have folders ConsoleApp1, ConsoleApp2, test01, test02 and file consoleApp2.sln. Project depends only of folders ConsoleApp1, ConsoleApp2 and file consoleApp2.sln. I need map these and ignore the folders test01 and test02.

This is my folder structure and Workspace mappings:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: This worked. Thank you very much Vito. You solved my problem!